# Erro Spring boot - Liquibase

Tags: java, spring, boot, liquibase

18-04-15 23:10:21.452  INFO 9464 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-04-15 23:10:21.470  INFO 9464 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-15 23:10:21.484 ERROR 9464 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find changelog location: class path resource [db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml] (please add changelog or check your Liquibase configuration)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]

Estou com esse erro, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Vc criou um arquivo de changelog no caminho padrão (`db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml`)?

Comment: Sim, está feito sim. O estranho é que eu copie de um projeto em que sobe normalmente, e nesse ele não quer subir.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
 <property name="TYPE_ID" value="varchar(36)" />

Comment: <property name="TYPE_DESCRICAO" value="varchar(25)" />
 <include file="db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml"/>
  </databaseChangeLog>

Answer (score 0):

No Spring boot tem uma configuração pro liquibase que informa o local do teu arquivo de changelog, considerando que a pasta "db" esteja na pasta "resources" do projeto. Segue exemplo:

```
liquibase.change-log = classpath:db/changelog.xml
```